# Using a for loop to return variable name - variable mean in R

Tags: r, database, for-loop, if-statement

I'm trying to create a for loop which returns both the variable name and its mean first extracting numeric variables of a given database. I'm using the mtcars database so this can be replicated with base R code:

```
data(mtcars)

# Force 2 variables to factors (if code works fine, output will have 9 rows)
mtcars$vs <- as.factor(mtcars$vs)
mtcars$am <- as.factor(mtcars$am)


# The loop
for (i in mtcars[,1:length(mtcars)]){
if(is.numeric(i))
{
print(mean(i))
}
}

#Result (9 rows as expected)
[1] 20.09062
[1] 6.1875
[1] 230.7219
[1] 146.6875
[1] 3.596563
[1] 3.21725
[1] 17.84875
[1] 3.6875
[1] 2.8125
```

Now, my idea is that the loop returns something like this:

```
[1] mpg: 20.09062
[1] cyl: 6.1875
[1] disp: 230.7219
```

But, when I try to extract the names of numeric variables I got null for all values:

```
for (i in mtcars[,1:length(mtcars)]){
if(is.numeric(i))
{
print(names(i))
}
}
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
```

So, for example:

```
for (i in mtcars[,1:length(mtcars)]){
if(is.numeric(i))
{
print(paste(names(i))," Mean:", mean(i)) 
}
}
```

obviously doesn't work.

I'm aware that I can find some easier solutions, but I must emphasize that this question is basically for going more in depth with loops, so I will appreciate if any advice could be given using the code I exposed as starting point.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
for (i in 1:ncol(mtcars))
{
  if(is.numeric(mtcars[,i]))
  {
    cat(paste(names(mtcars)[i],":",mean(mtcars[,i]),"\n"))
  }
}
```

Your output:

```
mpg : 20.090625 
cyl : 6.1875 
disp : 230.721875 
hp : 146.6875 
drat : 3.5965625 
wt : 3.21725 
qsec : 17.84875 
gear : 3.6875 
carb : 2.8125
```

Answer (score 3):

The way you have defined the loop, you don't have the names anymore.

Better do:

```
for (i in 1:length(mtcars)) {
  if (is.numeric(mtcars[, i])) {
    print(paste(names(mtcars)[i], "Mean:", mean(mtcars[, i])))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if we need to do this on a condition, use `summarise_if`

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% 
     summarise_if(is.numeric, mean)
```

---

If we need a `for` loop

```
for (nm in names(mtcars)){
 if(is.numeric(mtcars[, nm])) {
   print(paste0(nm, " :",  mean(mtcars[,nm])))

}

}

#[1] "mpg :20.090625"
#[1] "cyl :6.1875"
#[1] "disp :230.721875"
#[1] "hp :146.6875"
#[1] "drat :3.5965625"
#[1] "wt :3.21725"
#[1] "qsec :17.84875"
#[1] "gear :3.6875"
#[1] "carb :2.8125"
```

Comment: As I exposed, I know there are many solutions but I'm trying to solve this using the code I posted as starting point. Thanks :)